# Angular 0Auth How to handle response for secured calls (ie. bookmarks)

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, bookmarks

I'm searching the web for some ideas, but probably here will be the best place to get does anyway.

**Setup**

I will be creating an Angular 6 app for frontend with a Spring Boot 2(Spring 5) backend app to be used as REST API. User Authentication will be done using Google and GitHub OAuth2.

**Problem**
A user will have the possibility to go to any given url (ie. my-domain.com/transactions?from=2014&to2016), now this location is secured, it requires to be authenticated. Meaning, Guard that would be executed for any secured route, and check if the 'user details endpoint' would return data or unauthorised status. If a user was not yet authenticated, he would be redirected to given login page and after success would be redirected back to the frontend. I would like to redirect the user to the url that he was asking for (not to the home page).

The problem that I see is that while sending a request for authenticating a user, I would like to somehow tell the backend, two which url the user would like to be redirected back after the process is finished. 
Now, I can of course create a custom endpoint on which I would receive this first request (with the redirect url) and redirected to the OAuth service as usual, but the problem is how to be informed with used is coming back from the authorisation system by executing the callback redirect url. What was the url two which that user wanted to be redirected. 
I Fill like this info should be also be a part (as a parameter) of the request to the OAuth system, but now I don't see that as an option as I don't have such money to ask Github or Google to add this to their OAuth features :)

Is there any pattern that could be used in this case, or is this just a no no, and I need to do some heavy workaround (either on the backend or the frontend side) ?